# Dollar sign as a string parameter in Jenkins job is doubled

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I builded Jenkins with parameters in my configuration:

```
a = a$
b = b$$
c = c$$$
d = d$$$$
e = e$e$e$e$
```

I builded my pipeline and it contained this possibilities how to display content of environment variables:

```
sh """
    echo "${env.a}"
    echo "\$a"
    echo "${env.b}"
    echo "\$b"
    echo "${env.c}"
    echo "\$c"
    echo "${env.d}"
    echo "\$d"
    echo "${env.e}"
    echo "\$e"
"""
```

It returned:

```
+ echo 'a$'
a$
+ echo 'a$$'
a$$
+ echo 'b$'
b$
+ echo 'b$$'
b$$
+ echo c14
c14
+ echo 'c$$$$'
c$$$$
+ echo d14
d14
+ echo 'd$$$$'
d$$$$
+ echo 'eeee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$14'
eeee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$14
+ echo 'ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$'
ee$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$e$$$$
```

Anyone who can explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - very interesting problem. Results are... unusual :)

I couldn't reproduce 100% of your results on my Jenkins, it's probably version/platform dependent. But fortunately the most interesting parameter `e` returned all that mess. So I'll focus on in.

It looks like parameters are evaluated before they are passed to environment. So each occurrence of `$e` is replaced by current value of `e` variable (which is `e$e$e$e$` so far). So, we have `e` then three times `$e` replaced by `e$e$e$e$` and finally `$`. The result is: `e e$e$e$e$ e$e$e$e$ e$e$e$e$ $` (spaces added for readability). And this is value stored in environment. You can see it printed by your last `echo` (but with every `$` replaced by `$$`).

The longest output (`echo "${env.e}"`) doesn't do anything new - it just takes `ee$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$$` and evaluates it one more time, replacing every occurrence of `$e` by `ee$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$e$$`. And finally, replaces every `$` by `$$` when printing :)

Comment: Is it possible to escape them? I was expecting, that if it is passed as string parameter, it will hold the data type. First of all, it should be a string and definitely not evaluated - I suppose it could potentially be a security bug.

Comment: It's evaluated intentionally, but the problem is that it allows self references, which looks like a bug to me. Even stranger it is because source code seem to handle this scenario. I'm not a Java programmer, but [this part](https://github.com/jenkinsci/envinject-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/envinject/service/EnvInjectEnvVars.java#L310) is intended to avoid that problem.

Comment: It looks like `$` + letters is interpreted as variable and nothing can change it (`\$` doesn't work). The only way I found was combining value like: `a = $`, `b = e`, `e = $a$b`. Which is extremely ugly and cumbersome.

Comment: And why is dollar sign always doubled? Any ideas? What is interesting is also that there is difference between `echo "${env.a}"` and `echo "\$a"`.

Comment: Intentional evaluation of string parameter seems to me clearly as a bug. But I can be missing the point. I can see the use case but to be honest, I wouldn't expect it. I was really surprised, when I found out, that string is passed changed.

Comment: It seems to be problem to use also these symbols in parameters `$ \ " ' `.

Comment: Documented here - https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation